# How do i make a custom cursor on html?

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

```css
body { 
  cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
}
```

I've tried to have it be as an external link, it did not work. I have also tried to add `""` inside of the url with both an internal and external link and it did not work.

- Image size is 840x859.
- It's inside of <style> tag.
- I use Visual Studio Code 2019

Comment: Where is cursor.png stored and where is your stylesheet stored?

Comment: Maybe try with a smaller image? That's a very large cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```css
body {
    cursor: url('https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-custom-cursor.ico'), default;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```

Comment: it works. Thank you. Is it working because the file is an icon or is it because its a certain resolution?

Comment: @kittylover Does it work with *your* image? What did you have to change?

Comment: png files work in general as well, depends which browsers you want to support. See [CanIUse curser url](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_cursor_url). Maybe you are testing in android browser?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I compressed the file to 64x64 pixels and used the code above which made it work. I also had the image in the same file as the page im using that cursor.